# Construction of a a table or DataFrame from a list of tuples with different fields

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
data = [
('abc','Name','Abe','def'),
('w32','reportedDateTime','20170630172658','4r3'),
('r43','type','54A','tr4'),
('t765e','fileDate','06/30/2017','q'),
('4','assignedCode','333-215239','80'),

('54','Name','Brenda','re'),
('ht56','State','Arizona','54g')
('a','reporteddatetime','20170630172550','4r3'),

('65ky355','Name','Cathy','67737grr'),
('65t','type','R59','6yy3h'),
('k6r43d','zip','94110','yt65'),
('6589','filedate','08/12/2016','67rr')
```

]

I want to form a table or a pandas dataframe or maybe store in a relational databse like mySql (unless some one things a different databse will be better) in the following format.
The 1st element of the tuple and the last element is to be discarded.
The 2nd element is to serve as the column header.
The third element will be the value for that column.

So , the result would be something like:

Name    ReportedDateTime  Type  FileDate    AssignedCode  Zip  State
Abe      20170630172658     54A    06/30/2017  333-215239
Brenda    20170630172658  Arizona
Cathy R59  08/12/2016 94110

I am not sure how to format the table correctly,  here but it is essentially a table with 3 rows (PLUS one header row) and 7 columns.
But not all the cells have values for instance the Zip column will have a value only for the 3rd row, i.e. Cathy. Similarly the AssignedCode will have a value only for the first row Abe.
There is a DateTime field, a Date field and a zip field, and I also need to format the fields appropriately. so that the table/database is sortable by dateTime or data or Name or type etc.

[image]

Comment: I think these might help I found them by googling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342949/create-a-table-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-python-3 AND https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataFrame` constructor first and then reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), each row is count by occurencies of `Name` in second column:

```
data = [
('abc','Name','Abe','def'),
('w32','reporteddatetime','20170630172658','4r3'),
('r43','type','54A','tr4'),
('t765e','filedate','06/30/2017','q'),
('4','assignedCode','333-215239','80'),

('54','Name','Brenda','re'),
('ht56','State','Arizona','54g'),
('a','reporteddatetime','20170630172550','4r3'),

('65ky355','Name','Cathy','67737grr'),
('65t','type','R59','6yy3h'),
('k6r43d','zip','94110','yt65'),
('6589','filedate','08/12/2016','67rr')

]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = list('abcd'))

df = df.set_index([(df['b'] == 'Name').cumsum(), 'b'])['c'].unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
b    Name    State assignedCode    filedate reporteddatetime  type    zip
0     Abe     None   333-215239  06/30/2017   20170630172658   54A   None
1  Brenda  Arizona         None        None   20170630172550  None   None
2   Cathy     None         None  08/12/2016             None   R59  94110
```

Comment: Thanks. This works only if the column 'b' has no duplicate entries. Unfortunately, my list of tuples has duplicates.
So, while I am able to construct a dataframe from the list of tuples while reataining the original structure, where I am getting stuck at is in creating the subsequent dataframe/table. 
The tuple with the tag 'Name' in the 2nd position marks the beginning of a new record for that Name. But the same name can have several records associated with it. And the fields for a record (even for the same name) can vary.

Comment: OK, but how is possible distinguish start of beginning new row? Can you create sample ot tuples closer to real data?